# How to disable a4j:commandLink

Tags: jsf-2, ajax4jsf

I have an a4j:commandLink and I want to disable it when it is clicked.
I write the code like this:

```
    <a4j:commandLink id="link"
       onclick="this.disabled=true;"
       action="#{jobAction.action}"
       <h:graphicImage value="/img/last-enable.gif" />
    </a4j:commandLink>
```

but it does not work. The same code can work in the a4j:commandButton, why a4j:commandLink can't? Anyone can tell me how to implement that function? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you initially set `onclick="return false;"` you cannot run the action even once.
So you have to set it dynamically as below.

```
<a4j:commandLink onclick="this.setAttribute('onclick', 'return false;');"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

the `disabled` property applies only on `input` elements.

Please try `return false;` instead and add special style so the link will look disabled.

```
<a4j:commandLink id="link"
   onclick="return false;"
   action="#{jobAction.action}"
   style="text-decoration: none; color: #dedede; cursor: default;"
   <h:graphicImage value="/img/last-enable.gif" />
</a4j:commandLink>
```